Pod is hanging in terminating state
I have kubernetes CRON job that invokes simple script that is cloning git repository to persistent storage. Job is invoked every 15 minutes and once per day or two I have job that is not finishing and it has status 'Terminating' (script has done all jobs because I can see final message from script in logs).
│   Warning  FailedKillPod  14h (x94 over 2d10h)       kubelet  error killing pod: [failed to "KillContainer" for "pull-repo" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = an error occurs during waiting for container \"3ff92cf6a48e46345e635a5bbc8f20d334c84 │
│ 927b7e700076f9c795799029d19\" to be killed: wait container \"3ff92cf6a48e46345e635a5bbc8f20d334c84927b7e700076f9c795799029d19\": context deadline exceeded", failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "34ceec99-8a5e-45b8-a298-cdf2ae8e43df" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Dead │
│ lineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│   Warning  FailedKillPod  7h20m (x110 over 2d10h)    kubelet  error killing pod: [failed to "KillContainer" for "pull-repo" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded", failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "34ceec99-8a5e-45b8-a298- │
│ cdf2ae8e43df" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to stop container \"3ff92cf6a48e46345e635a5bbc8f20d334c84927b7e700076f9c795799029d19\": an error occurs during waiting for container \"3ff92cf6a48e46345e635a5bbc8f20d334c84927b7e700076f9 │
│ c795799029d19\" to be killed: wait container \"3ff92cf6a48e46345e635a5bbc8f20d334c84927b7e700076f9c795799029d19\": context deadline exceeded"]                                                                                                                                       │
│   Warning  FailedKillPod  5h49m (x446 over 2d10h)    kubelet  error killing pod: [failed to "KillContainer" for "pull-repo" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded", failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "34ceec99-8a5e-45b8-a298- │
│ cdf2ae8e43df" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded"]                                                                                                                                                                       │
│   Warning  Unhealthy      4m52s (x21033 over 2d10h)  kubelet  (combined from similar events): Readiness probe errored: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "1498eacd7dc6dfb402d060fb64114336fb9994060c9ac718aea16c3bd92f6fd8": OCI ru │
│ ntime exec failed: exec failed: cannot exec in a stopped container: unknown

When I try to delete this pod my command also hangs and only way that is working is delete with force.
Any ideas what can be source of this behavior?
My job definition
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-name
spec:
  schedule: "*/15 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      parallelism: 1
      completions: 1
      backoffLimit: 3
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 120
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 10800
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: job-sa
          containers:
            - name: name
              image: image_name:1.00.00
              resources:
                requests:
                  memory: "150Mi"
                  cpu: "25m"
                limits:
                  memory: "300Mi"
                  cpu: "50m"
              livenessProbe:
                exec:
                  command: ["ls"]
              readinessProbe:
                exec:
                  command: ["ls"]
              command: ["/bin/sh"]
              args:
                - -c
                - /scripts/pull-repo.sh |& while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z')" "$line"; done |& tee -a /opt/logs/app/pull-repo/pull-repo.log
              volumeMounts:
                - name: config-server-repo-volume
                  mountPath: /tmp/git_repo_clone
                - name: git-repo-ssh-volume
                  mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/.ssh/config
                  subPath: config
                - name: git-repo-ssh-volume
                  mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/.ssh/id_rsa
                  subPath: id_rsa
                - name: git-repo-ssh-volume
                  mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/.ssh/known_hosts
                  subPath: known_hosts
                - name: scripts-volume
                  mountPath: /scripts/pull-repo.sh
                  subPath: pull-repo.sh
          volumes:
            - name: scripts-volume
              configMap:
                name: config-server-scripts
                defaultMode: 0750
            - name: git-repo-ssh-volume
              secret:
                secretName: git-repo-ssh
                defaultMode: 0640
            - name: config-server-repo-volume
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: configserver-pvc
          restartPolicy: OnFailure

Job description
Name:                     config-server-worker-28664520
Namespace:                mynamespace
Selector:                 batch.kubernetes.io/controller-uid=0a368975-a112-47be-bcf5-8451a6ec90e5
Annotations:              batch.kubernetes.io/job-tracking:
Controlled By:            CronJob/config-server-worker
Parallelism:              1
Completions:              1
Completion Mode:          NonIndexed
Start Time:               Tue, 02 Jul 2024 00:00:00 +0200
Active Deadline Seconds:  120s
Pods Statuses:            0 Active (1 Ready) / 0 Succeeded / 1 Failed
Pod Template:
  Service Account:  config-server-sa
  Init Containers:
   logs-directory-creator:
    Image:      image:8.6
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
    Args:
      -c
      mkdir -p /opt/logs/app_containers/{app//mynamespace//config-server-worker//${K8S__POD_NAME}//pull-repo,audit//mynamespace//config-server-worker//${K8S__POD_NAME}//pull-repo} && chmod ugo+rwx /opt/logs/app_containers/{app//mynamespace//config-server-worker//${K8S__POD_NAME}//pull-repo,audit//mynamespace//config-server-worker//${K8S__POD_NAME}//pull-repo}
    Environment:
      K8S__POD_NAME:   (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /opt/logs/app_containers from root-logs-directory (rw)
  Containers:
   pull-repo:
    Image:      image:1.20.10
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
    Args:
      -c
      /scripts/pull-repo.sh |& while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z')" "$line"; done |& tee -a /opt/logs/app/${K8S__POD_NAME}/pull-repo/pull-repo.log
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  300Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      25m
      memory:   150Mi
    Liveness:   exec [ls] delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  exec [ls] delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      K8S__CONTAINER_NAME:  pull-repo
      K8S__POD_UID:          (v1:metadata.uid)
      K8S__POD_IP:           (v1:status.podIP)
      K8S__POD_NAMESPACE:    (v1:metadata.namespace)
      K8S__POD_NAME:         (v1:metadata.name)
      K8S__NODE_NAME:        (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /etc/podinfo from podinfo (rw)
      /opt/app-root/src/.ssh/config from git-repo-ssh-volume (rw,path="config")
      /opt/app-root/src/.ssh/id_rsa from git-repo-ssh-volume (rw,path="id_rsa")
      /opt/app-root/src/.ssh/known_hosts from git-repo-ssh-volume (rw,path="known_hosts")
      /opt/logs/app/ from app-logs (rw)
      /opt/logs/audit/ from audit-logs (rw)
      /scripts/pull-repo.sh from scripts-volume (rw,path="pull-repo.sh")
      /tmp/git_repo_clone from config-server-repo-volume (rw)
  Volumes:
   audit-logs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt/logs/app_containers/audit/mynamespace/config-server-worker
    HostPathType:
   app-logs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt/logs/app_containers/app/mynamespace/config-server-worker
    HostPathType:
   podinfo:
    Type:  DownwardAPI (a volume populated by information about the pod)
    Items:
      metadata.labels -> labels
      metadata.annotations -> annotations
   root-logs-directory:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt/logs/app_containers
    HostPathType:
   scripts-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      config-server-scripts
    Optional:  false
   git-repo-ssh-volume:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  git-repo-ssh
    Optional:    false
   config-server-repo-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  configserver-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate  9h    job-controller  Created pod: config-server-worker-28664520-bt2tx
  Normal   SuccessfulDelete  9h    job-controller  Deleted pod: config-server-worker-28664520-bt2tx
  Warning  DeadlineExceeded  9h    job-controller  Job was active longer than specified deadline


Did you look at container logs ? Maybe it's hanging during git cloning.

Unfortunately, I see logs after git operations on the end of the script so I'm sure all script were executed and it should finish.

Can you do kubectl describe job <hanging job name> and share it in your question?

I updated my post with job description

Please ensure cron job clear old pods before starting a new one
This can be achieved using flag spec.jobTemplate.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds
So all of running Pods will be terminated and the Job status will become type: Failed with reason DeadlineExceeded.
Below is an example:
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello

    spec:
      schedule: "*/10 * * * *"
      jobTemplate:
        spec:
          activeDeadlineSeconds: 60

This ensures cron job clear old pods before starting a new one.

I edited my post with full job definition - I have activeDeadlineSeconds
